# MySQL error when running `rails server`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I get the following error when I run `rails server`

```
Could not find mysql2-0.2.7 in any of the sources
```

Any ideas? How do i fix this?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Add `gem 'mysql'` in GEMFILE. or you already had?

Comment: i already have the mysql and mysql2 gems

Comment: do you entry for them in GEMFILE like I suggested in 1st comment?

Comment: where do i find the GEMFILE on MAC @Harry Joy? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Imran: in your rails project folder.

Comment: @Harry Joy thanks it worked! All i did was change the 'gem mysql2' to 'gem mysql' in the GEMFILE. Any idea why i got this error in the first place?

Comment: @Imran - your adapter in database.yml is using mysql2 instead of mysql

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you have the version number specified next to the gem, try removing it, just do

gem 'mysql2' in your Gemfile,

Then run "bundle install", that should do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to go read up on Bundler: http://gembundler.com/

Bundler is included in Rails 3 by default.  At the root of your app is a file called

```
Gemfile
```

You should only use `mysql` or `mysql2`. I recommend `mysql2` so if you have more than one in your Gemfile then remove the others.  Then make sure you run `bundle install`.

For complete instructions on setting up MySQL and Rails on OSX, check out this blog post:

[Preferred Rails 3 and MySQL Installation on OSX Snow Leopard](http://michaelfarmer.info/preferred-rails-3-and-mysql-installation-on-o)